# How to disable the Win key if it's the only key being pressed using AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, windows-key

I often find myself tapping the <kbd>Win</kbd> key by mistake, how to disable it when it's the only key being pressed using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)?

In other words, tapping <kbd>Win</kbd> shouldn't bring up the start menu, but the <kbd>Win</kbd> key combination shortcuts should still work, e.g. pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> should open the quick link menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [#MenuMaskKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MenuMaskKey.htm#Remarks):

> The Start Menu (or the active window's menu bar) can be suppressed by sending any keystroke. The following example disables the ability for the left <kbd>Win</kbd> to activate the Start Menu, while still allowing its use as a modifier:
>
> ```
> ~LWin::Send {Blind}{vkE8}
> ```

Quote from [Blind mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind):

> The Blind mode can be enabled with `{Blind}`, which gives the script more control by disabling several things that are normally done automatically to make things work as expected.

`~LWin::Send {vkE8}` may not work in some cases without `{Blind}`.